# google datastore put_multi didn't insert data

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to insert 6000 rows/`entities` into `google cloud datastore`. I am also using `datastore emulator` as the local server.

In the code, I created an insert function that inserts entities in batches using `put_multi` and set the batch size to 50. I use `python multiprocessing` to spawn processes that execute the function.

A slice function is also used to divide the workload based on how many CPU cores are used. e.g. if there are 3 cores, the workload (6000 `entities`) is divided into 3 parts with 2000 `entities` each, then each part is inserted by a spawned process that executes the insert function.

After insertion is done, I checked with `Cloud Datastore Admin` console, but couldn't find the `kinds` that have been inserted.

I am wondering what is the issue here and how to solve it.

code snippet is as follows,

```
# cores_to_use is how many cpu cores available for dividing workload
cores_to_use = 3

# a datastore client is passed in as the argument
inserter = FastInsertGCDatastore(client)

# entities is a list of datastore entities to be inserted
# the number of entities is 6000 here
input_size = len(entities)
slice_size = int(input_size / cores_to_use)
entity_blocks = []

iterator = iter(entities)
for i in range(cores_to_use):
    entity_blocks.append([])
    for j in range(slice_size):
        entity_blocks[i].append(iterator.__next__())

for block in entity_blocks:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=inserter.execute, args=(block,))
    p.start()


class FastInsertGCDatastore:
    """
    batch insert entities into gc datastore based on batch_size and number_of_entities
    """
    def __init__(self, client):
        """
        initialize with datastore client
        :param client: the datastore client
        """
        self.client = client

    def execute(self, entities):
        """
        batch insert entities
        :param entities: a list of datastore entities need to be inserted
    """
        number_of_entities = len(entities)

        batch_size = 50

        batch_documents = [0] * batch_size
        rowct = 0  # entity count as index for accessing rows
        for index in range(number_of_entities):
            try:
                batch_documents[index % batch_size] = entities[rowct]
                rowct += 1
                if (index + 1) % batch_size == 0:
                    self.client.put_multi(batch_documents)
                index += 1
            except Exception as e:
                print('Unexpected error for index ', index, ' message reads', str(e))
                raise e

        # insert any remaining entities 
        if not index % batch_size == 0:
            self.client.put_multi(batch_documents[:index % batch_size])
```

Comment: any code to go with this issue?

Comment: @Samson updated OP with a code snippet.